# Merging trunk into a branch, not getting a new folder from trunk

Tags: svn, merge

I need to get a folder from the trunk (a feature that was implemented) and merge it into a branch.

So I've done these:

```
svn update .
svn merge ^/trunk ^/branches/mybranch
```

Got about 12 tree conflicts which said "Local edit, incoming replace upon merge" (*could somebody explain this message?*) which I resolved with `svn resolve --accept working *`.

The problem is that the `/trunk/feature/` folder wasn't created into the branch.

What is the proper way of doing that?

Using `svn copy ^/trunk/feature ^/branches/mybranch/feature`?

**Edit:**
More info:

- svn, version 1.7.5
- Branch was created with `svn mkdir branch/mybranch` and `svn copy ^/trunk ^/branch/mybranch`
- Indeed, this was the command I gave, but I've just ran `svn merge ^/trunk .` and after 3 conflicts which where resolved as above, the `/feature` folder hasn't been created

Comment: It's really hard to help with merge problems without more information than you're giving.  What version of Subversion?  How did you create your branch (copy from trunk, some other branch, etc...).  Your merge command given also can't be the exact command you gave since the target (second argument to merge) has to be a working copy path.  Also can you describe the changes that have been made to your branch since it was created (ideally as compared to trunk).

Comment: Actually on further thought, I forgot about the 2 URL merge and I think this is the problem behind your situation.  Answer coming shortly.

Comment: @BenReser: I've added more info to my question, thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is probably that you're using the 3rd form of the merge command, the '2-URL merge'.  This is probably not what you intend.

You probably want to run:

```
svn merge ^/trunk .
```

If you only want to pull in the changes that added the feature and not sync everything from trunk you're going to have to cherry pick them.  I'd suggest that you run `svn log ^/trunk/feature` and all the revisions listed by that be used with merge like so:

```
svn merge -c '1234, 1235, 1236' ^/trunk .
```

That assumes that all the needed changes take place just in the feature directory.  I'm guessing you may need other revisions but I can't really tell you how to select them.

The 2-URL merge is primarily intended for merging unrelated branches, which is not what you're doing.

Subversion always does merges into a working copy.  So your command is defaulting to actually running:

```
svn merge ^/trunk ^/branches/mybranch .
```

Where the last argument, the target working copy, is being assumed implicitly.

Sidenote: You also don't need to `svn mkdir` the branch before the copy.  Since your copy will just replace the branch.  Obviously if the branches folder doesn't exist you'll want to do `svn mkdir ^/branches` but that's a one time step.

Comment: Great, It worked with cherry picking! But if I really needed to merge trunk into branch, I would run this command `svn merge ^/trunk ^/branches/mybranch .` ?

Comment: No, you'd want to do `svn merge ^/trunk .`  The 2-URL form is something you almost never need to use.

Answer (score 0):

Is source branch folder empty?  I don't remember if it is SVN or Git, but IIRC one of these doesn't add folders if they're empty.  Could it be this in your case?

Comment: You're thinking of git.  Subversion versions trees including empty directories.

Answer (score 0):

Just addition to Ben's answer

If

> 3 conflicts which where resolved as above

i.e with `--accept working`

for **any** tree-conflict you'll never get new folder from `their` created obviously

Comment: You mean as it's a tree conflict I cannot use anything else than `--accept working`, so this is why no folder was created?

Comment: @Chris - you **must do something in order to avoid** tree-conflict, because `----accept working` will not allow any "foreign" change appear in your WC (and added into trunk folder is such change)

Comment: What can I do? Could you direct me to some directions to read?